# Java Business Rule to apply to setter to limit String length and insert space if limit exceeded

Tags: java

I have this setter method:

```
        public void setCgp_name(String cgp_name) {
        this.cgp_name = cgp_name;
    }
```

Basically when the user inserts a long string such as ARG,AUS,BEL,BRA,DNK,FRA,ITA,GBR,USA without any spaces between the commas this info is placed into a table and it will break the boundaries of the table. I am trying to apply a business rule to this setter so that if the user enters something like this : ARG,AUS,BEL,BRA,DNK,FRA,ITA,GBR,USA a space will be added in somewhere to prevent the formatting issue in the table. The word wrapping works when spaces are present but not with long strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public void setCgp_name(String cgp_name) {

        cgp_name = cgp_name.replaceAll(",[ ]*", ", ");

        this.cgp_name = cgp_name;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain why this helps and should be the selected solution. The goal is to educate so others can learn.